# Delphi/FireDAC using default schema instead of search_path on insert/update commands in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, delphi, schema, firedac

I've been using **FireDAC** for a couple of years now and somehow this problem never came up.

We are using **Postgres** database with a couple of **schemas** defined. Each user has a Postgres **Search_path** defined and till now we mostly used schema1.

Example:

```
ALTER ROLE user1 SET search_path = schema1, schema2, schema3;
```

Now, in **Delphi** all queries and tables were defined without a schema (we all thought search_path is doing it's job) and while we were only using schema1 everything was working fine.

But whenever I use a table from either schema2 or schema3 only Open operation works as intended. **Post fails with error 'relation "schema1.tableX" does not exist' even though tableX is of a different schema.**

[Relation does not exist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwVdB.gif)
What am I missing here? Thank you all in advance ...

I'm using Delphi Tokyo and Postgres 10.1 and datasets were connected to DevExpress grids. Also this behavior is verifiable on two seperate application using different schemas ... well, that part is probably understandable since they are both being developed and updated by me.

**Possible steps to repeat this:**

```
Postgres:
        ALTER ROLE user1 SET search_path = schema1, schema2; -- Default schema is schema1

    schema1.table1
    schema1.table2

    schema2.table3
    schema2.table4

Delphi:
table3.Tablename := 'table3';

table3 is connected to a TcxGrid via a Datasource.

table3.Open;

Then use either GUI or code to edit/insert a record.
```

**Post operation should fail with error 'relation "schema1.table3" does not exist'.**

[Sample project - just enter connection credentials and enter non-default schema tablename](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OU-ffa6PqJQHkLXCLYhgC_F43GVKSZbD/view?usp=sharing)

```
DDL:
CREATE DATABASE "AsystSQLProd"
  WITH OWNER = "AsystSQL"
       ENCODING = 'UTF8'
       TABLESPACE = ts_asyst_data
       LC_COLLATE = 'C'
       LC_CTYPE = 'C'
       CONNECTION LIMIT = -1;

GRANT ALL ON DATABASE "AsystSQLProd" TO "AsystSQL";
GRANT CONNECT, TEMPORARY ON DATABASE "AsystSQLProd" TO "AsystSupportRole";
GRANT CONNECT, TEMPORARY ON DATABASE "AsystSQLProd" TO "AsystLicensingRole";
GRANT CONNECT, TEMPORARY ON DATABASE "AsystSQLProd" TO "AsystFitRole";
GRANT CONNECT, TEMPORARY ON DATABASE "AsystSQLProd" TO "AsystMatRole";
REVOKE ALL ON DATABASE "AsystSQLProd" FROM public;


CREATE SCHEMA fit AUTHORIZATION "AsystSQL";

GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA fit TO "AsystSQL";
GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA fit TO "AsystFitRole";
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA fit TO "AsystLicensingRole";
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA fit TO "AsystSupportRole";

CREATE SCHEMA mat AUTHORIZATION "AsystSQL";

GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA mat TO "AsystSQL";
GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA mat TO "AsystMatRole";


CREATE USER andrejg WITH
  LOGIN
  NOSUPERUSER
  INHERIT
  NOCREATEDB
  NOCREATEROLE
  NOREPLICATION
  VALID UNTIL 'infinity'

GRANT 
  "AsystFitRole", 
  "AsystMatRole", 
  "AsystSupportRole" TO andrejg;

ALTER USER andrejg SET search_path TO mat, sup, fit;
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce on Delphi 10.2 (.0), on PostgreSQL 10.1 (build 1800). I've executed a SQL command like `SELECT * FROM mytable` where `mytable` was a table defined under the schema listed as second in the `search_path` of a user that I was logged as on. Then I've tried to `Append` a tuple and `Post` changes. Tuple was inserted. Was that your workflow? If so, which versions do you use? If not, could you clarify, please?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out - I updated my question with the versions I'm using.

Comment: Well, then we have similar environment (if not same). I was not able to reproduce this thing. I was able to `Open` a `TFDQuery` with command fetching tuples from a table declared in `schema2` without mentioning schema in the command. Opening was fine, so as `Append`, modification and `Post`. Could you elaborate the steps? Or ideally post an MVCE, please?

Comment: Well, this is a conundrum ... I will try to create a minimal example ... BTW, how is your FDConnection set up?

Comment: Simply like `Database=MyDatabase; User_Name=user1; Password=12345; DriverID=PG`. Have tried even `TDBGrid` with defined columns and fields at design time. Still no problem. Can edit with no error.

Comment: I've added a simple sample project that reproduces this error on my machine. If you cannot reproduce this there must be a glitch or something badly configured on my end.

Comment: `Table3` becoming `table3` in the error message looks like it is lower casing it for you which would be wrong if the table really does start with a capital and will produce the error you see.

Comment: @Brian, in such case the OP would not be able to even open the table object. Andrej, still cannot reproduce (I've tested even character case by enclosing table names with `""` chars). Still able to open and edit table, with no problems.

Comment: Yeah, character case certainly not a problem ... @Victoria, thanks for helping ... must be something off with my config. Thanks again!

Comment: I'd like to find the issue (and fix it). PostgreSQL is my favorite DBMS and FireDAC my favorite client library. Could you share even DDL (including that user definition), please?

Comment: @Victoria I've added data definition for user and schemas in question. Tell me if you notice anything ... btw, do you utilize MetaCurSchema or MetaDefSchema properties on the FDConnection.Params?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place `public` before the rest of the schemes:

```
ALTER DATABASE DBName SET search_path TO public, schema1, schema2
```

Comment: Every post must be written in English.

Comment: HA! It's been two years ... I've worked around this problem, but yeah ... this is confirmed. It works!! Thank you, man!!